# Rendering Different Text In The Same View

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In new.html.erb, I have the following form:

```
<div align="center">
<h1>What are your important <%= @category.bizdev %> Action items?</h1>

<%= form_for @category do |f| %>
<p>

<p>Store Answer Below:</p>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :size => 40, :style => 'height: 40px' %>
</p>

<p>
<%=f.submit 'Save action item' %>
</p>
<% end %> </div>
```

The @category.bizdev on the second line is calling the method bizdev, from the model Category:

```
def bizdev
  "Business Development"
end
```

But - I have an index page:

```
<h1>Select A Business Category To Begin Identifying Action Items</h1>

<ol><li><%= link_to 'Business Admin', 'new' %></li><br><br>
<li><%= link_to 'Business Development/Marketing', 'new' %></li><br><br>
<li><%= link_to 'Financial', 'new' %></li>
</ol>


 <%= link_to 'Store random action items', new_facilitate_path %><br><br>

 <%= link_to 'See a list of already stored action items', facilitates_path %>
```

That links to the same new view, with different category names (business dev, business arm, business financial). I need the view to render the appropriate NAME, or business category, based on the URL that is clicked to send to the new form.

If I am not being clear, let me know. If you need more of my code, let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems like you're combining the concepts of a category and a category action. Splitting them might clarify your design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand you correctly and I think you should

1. pass a category name in params
2. define a helper which returns correct category name

for example code might be like this (pay attention on route helpers in `link_to`)

```
#index page
# pay attention on routes!
<ol>
  <li><%= link_to 'Business Admin', new_category_path(category_name: 'Business Admin') %></li><br><br>
  <li><%= link_to 'Business Development/Marketing', new_category_path(category_name: 'Business Development/Marketing') %></li><br><br>
  <li><%= link_to 'Financial', new_category_path(category_name: 'Financial') %></li>
</ol>

# new page 
<h1>What are your important <%= bizdev %> Action items?</h1>

# helper
def bizdev
  if ['Business Admin', 'Business Development/Marketing', 'Financial'].include?(params[:category_name])
    params[:category_name]
  else
    @category.bizdev
  end
end
```

Some explanations:

1. `include?` it is just a protection that params `category_name` belongs to allowed values (if invalid value comes in params then default value is used)
2. `category_name` come in url params. You should understand that user can pass any value that is I prefer to check params value.
3. "How does Rails correspond the category_name with the appropriate category_name on the index view?" - You build `link_to` with correct `category_name` as params (see index page example)
4. Example above it is only for your case. Maybe you should change architecture a little bit. For example apply gem [`enumerize`](https://github.com/brainspec/enumerize) for category attribute `name`. Then in controller action `new` build new object with passed params `category_name`.

example of code

```
# model
enumerize :name, in: [:business_admin, :business_development, :financial], default: :financial # need to update locale file

#controller
def new
  @category = Category.new
  @category.name = params[:name] # rename params to `name`
end

# new page
<h1>What are your important <%= @category.name_text %> Action items?</h1>
```

Comment: Hmm! Ok @gotva - I think we're on the right track there. Let me give it a go and see what's up. Appreciate your time, really. I'll report back and mark answered if all is well. -- This helper method, should go within categories helper?

Comment: Ok - this worked. I posted the helper in categories helper. But how does this work? The if else statement, for example, the include method does what? And.. calling category_name in params.. where does "category_name" come from? How does Rails correspond the category_name with the appropriate category_name on the index view? -- either way, really awesome. I'll have to study this and learn what everything is doing.. Thanks a ton. Super appreciate your time.